# Read PHP cookie from JavaScript cookie

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

When I make a JavaScript cookie like this:

```
document.cookie = "hh=234,23423,324";
```

And I read it from PHP like this:

```
echo ($_COOKIE['hh']);
```

It is only returning the value: **234** and not: 234,23423,324

In google chrome resources tab the entire value is shown as '234,23423,324'.

Any information is helpful  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IpXg.png

Answer (score 3):

You need to store your cookie as a string and not as a number. Otherwise your cookie may be interpreted as number, stopping parsing at first non-digit character.

Try this in JavaScript: `document.cookie = 'hh="234,23423,324"';`

Read more in [Mozilla's cookie documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie).

Comment: it does not seem to be working, when using: document.cookie = 'hh="234,23423,324"'; php output is [hh] => 23

Comment: Can you check if your cookie content is `234,23423,324` or `"234,23423,324"` please ?

Comment: When using document.cookie = 'hh="234,23423,324"'; value is: "234,23423,324"

Comment: And output from PHP is then: 23